# How to hide E_USER_NOTICE errors in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, error-handling

I'm triggering an error in my Symfony2 project like this:

```
trigger_error('message', E_USER_NOTICE);
```

How can I suppress this error, such that I don't get a code 500 response but only get this notice logged with monolog?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `trigger_error` is not the recommend way to trigger errors in Symfony2. The recommend way to trigger errors in Symfony2 is to use [exceptions](http://php.net/exception). In Symfony2 you can use the global exceptions and the exceptions created by the Symfony2 framework and even exceptions you created in a bundle:

```php
<?php
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/Exception/FooException.php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Exception;

class FooException extends \Exception
{
}
```

```php
<?php
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/Controller/FooController.php

// ...
use Acme\DemoBundle\Exception\FooException;

// ...
public function barAction()
{
    // ... do something

    // throw an error
    throw new FooException('message');
}
```

But if you want to log something to a file you can better use one of the `monolog.logger` services (`doctrine`, `event`, `profiler`, `request`, `router`, `security` or `templating`). For more information, read [the monolog documentation](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/tree/master/doc). You can also create your own Monolog logger, create a service and use that.